# Set unsorted list equal to array of listed items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I've searched around quite a bit but could not find a solution to my problem so posting:

Using JQuery selectors to acquire html code, I am trying to ***set something equal to itself after modification***.

My understanding is that **l-value is of type unsortedList** while the **r-value is of type arrayOfListItems** (of course js is of an untyped language, but we are still talking about possibly a UL compared to an array of LIs).

So I'm guessing the two objects are of different types(structures), therefore not allowed initialization or perhaps it does, and an array of listedItems is generated where unintended causing the html to crash. Is there any way to properly set the UL equal to my sliced array of LI's?

With Respects to this:

```
<ul id="messages" type="text/plain"></ul>
```

The code:

```
socket.on('chat message', function(msg) {
    $('#messages').append($('&lt;li>').text(msg));
    maxList(10);
});
function maxList(maxLength) {
    var msgLength = $('#messages li').length;
    $('#messages').append($('&lt;li>').text(msgLength-maxLength));
    if(msgLength > maxLength) {
        $('#messages') = $('#messages li').slice(0,msgLength-maxLength);
        //Using selector to acquire the UL, trying to reinitialize it from ???,
        //    is the RHS even a UL?
    }
}
```

I've found solutions to setting a UL equal to another UL but my case diffs a tiny bit. Helps is appreciated, thanks.

Edited, fixed some auto indentation for legibility.

Comment: `$('&lt;li>').text(msg)`? you probly just wanna do `$('<li>'+msg+'</li>')`

Comment: Just to clarify, if you see any '&lt;' it was my replacement for left angle bracket '<' when inserting raw into <code></code> rather than highlighting and pressing the cool '{}' button.

Comment: how is that easier than highlighting and pressing a button? besides, all the button does is indent each line by 4 spaces.

Comment: Misreading? The '&lt;' was my initial replacement for angle bracket, before i started using to code button; left over artifacts from failed insert. The code button is definitely easier and cooler; we were always in agreement. Statements after 'rather' pointing to the "right way".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to re-define the element in `DOM` you can use jQuery `:gt()` pseudo selector, which is 0-based, and `.remove()`

```js
// remove `li` elements from parent `#messages` having index greater than 2
$("#messages li:gt(2)").remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<ul id="messages">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Nice. That alternative worked great. I'm about to mark as solved but I'm wondering something, "Newbie scripting questions": how would I implement it with a variable rather than constant? and also "for learning purposes" how was slice intended to be used with arrays? I'm guessing since slice returns the modified array I would be able to make a local variable and initialize it the returning value from the function slice, then insert each 'li' back into the 'ul', possibly with append; just wondering. Either ways, appreciate the help, thanks!

Comment: @dstackflow You could alternatively use `.html()` `$("#messages").html($("#messages li").slice(0,msgLength-maxLength));`

Comment: Does html() accept a Jquery object? I thought it had to be a string.

Comment: @PapaPearson877 Yes, `jQuery()` accepts a jQuery object as argument

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to replace #messages html with the sliced elements?

```
$("#messages li").slice(0,msgLength-maxLength).appendTo($("#messages").empty());
```

Like the other answer says, just removing the elements you want truncated may be easier and more clear.

Comment: Both correct, thanks for doing it my way. I'm going to mark the other one as correct, since it's a better design, but your answer was the correct one to my question.